# Why does electric field formed in depletion layer in pn junction acts as a barrier for the diffusion of charge carriers

Tags: semiconductor-physics

As we all know that in a pn junction depletion layer is formed and due to immobile charges electric field is directed from n side to p side but why does this electric field acts as a barrier for diffusion rather than an enhancer for diffusion of charge carriers?

Answer (score 3):

Positive charges feel a force in the direction of $\mathbf E$, while negative charges feel a force in the opposite direction. $p$-type carriers get pushed toward the $p$-side of the junction, and $n$-type carriers get pushed toward the $n$-side of the junction.